Exterior 125A subpanel for pedestal selection
I am building an outdoors area in my backyard that will necessitate of its own subpanel. I have placed 2in PCV sch40 conduit in the ground and I plan to pull wires to power a 125A panel. I will mount this panel on a pedestal in an area that while not being exposed to extreme weather, might be exposed to rain. The conduit will rise from underground of course.
When trying to lookup online, I see that most outdoor-rated panels have an entrance on top. To me that seems a good way to have water enter the panel - am I exxaggerating things?
Anything special I should take into account when I go at the electric distributor to ask for an outdoor-rated 125A subpanel or are they (besides known brand differences) more or less all equivalent?

A few things to consider:

Anything outdoor-rated should be OK. That being said, I am not so sure (one of the professionals may have a definitive answer) whether a panel on a pedestal is normally allowed or not. Normally panels are either on or in a wall.
125A is not a magic number. If you actually need 125A then anything 125A or larger will work. For example, you might find a 200A "main panel" and that's perfectly fine to use, even though it is a subpanel. In fact, except for a separate ground bar (often included with main panels but not necessarily, but inexpensive to add if needed) which is required for subpanels but not for main panels, there isn't anything fundamentally different between a main panel and a subpanel. A main panel includes a "main breaker", but with a subpanel not on/in your main building, you need a disconnect anyway, and a "main breaker", even if it is larger than the feed to the subpanel, works fine as a disconnect.
Feed size determines wire size. 125A requires 2/0 AWG aluminum wire. On the other hand, if you can make do with 90A then 2 AWG aluminum wire will do fine and save some money (both because it is smaller and because it is more common).
Load calculation is critical. In addition to making sure your subpanel has enough power to do everything you need it to do, you also need to do a main panel/utility service load calculation to see how much power is available for your subpanel. If you have 200A service then I doubt you'll have 125A to spare, but you may well have 50A or more. The way to do this (both for the main panel and the subpanel) is a formal NEC Load Calculation, not "guesswork", not "add breaker handles" (that will be too high), not "add up all the things you think you normally use" (that will often be too low).


Thanks for the answer. I have 400A service. This panel will likely see at times loads that approach 90A, so going for a 125A seems wise. I understand that a 200A panel will also work, I just did not want to use one that is physically too big (20 spaces are enough)
I need to figure out the pedestal part, as I literally do NOT have a wall in this location (loads are hydraulic pumps). I see that people with a swimming pool often have the electrical panel or a random and often poorly-built pedestal, so I did not think this would be a problem... I need to further investigate that

It's pretty common for pedestals to be made from Unistrut in commercial setups. You can do that at home too. A properly installed 3R rated panel is fine even with an entrance from the top, though they should also support entrance from the bottom. The style of entrance used in each location is different.

As far as entrance, in addition to usually having knockouts on all sides, most panels can be installed "upside down" because if your utility feed is coming from underground that is much better than having to loop it around.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- that's true for NEMA 1 panels but not NEMA 3R

Yeah I was planning to use two posts and unistruts running between them to secure the panel. The pedestal looks pretty trivial to build

The panel I am considering is HOM2040L125PRB, NEMA3R with 20 spaces. Annoyingly, the bottom (that I would use for all conduits) has a bunch of random knock-outs that will make my life miserable. I wish they just came with a flat bottom

How is that a problem? Can't you use conduit with the knockouts? They are standard sizes (10 0.5", 6 0.5"/0.75", 1 0.5"/0.75"/1.0", 1 1.0"-through-2.5")

Because I want my conduits to be all well aligned so it's easier to secure them to a unistrut.
